# Delete files after adding them into an archive

Tags: php

I have a question, so I need to delete all files from a directory which I added into an archive. I need to create another methode after zip() for delete files? Or I can do simultaneously?
My code for add in archive:

```
define("PATH_TO_FILES_FOR_ARCHIVE","/tmp/");
define("NOM_OF_ARCHIVE","/tmp/folder.zip");


addZip(PATH_TO_FILES_FOR_ARCHIVE, NOM_OF_ARCHIVE);

function addZip($source, $destination)
{
if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
    return false;
}

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
    return false;
}
$source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));
if (is_dir($source) === true)
{
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

        // Ignore "." and ".." folders
        if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
            continue;

        $file = realpath($file);

        if (is_dir($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
        }
        else if (is_file($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
        }
    }
}
else if (is_file($source) === true)
{
    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
}
return $zip->close();
 }
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Please do not abuse the tagging system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to delete it then you can delete it using the `unlink()` function, there is no need to write another procedure for it.

```
**Edited:**

else if (is_file($source) === true) //if this is a file then zip it
{
    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
 unlink($source)
}
```

Comment: Where I need to call this function?

Comment: you need to use the function, where you finish zipping the file. see this link for great example. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_unlink.asp. I am assuming that you are familiar with your code and know where file zipping occurs